# Swagger annotations for restful services with JSON data type and without Java Models usage

Tags: java, json, rest, swagger

I have written swagger annotations for my rest servcie like this.

```
@Post
@Path("/updateDocument")
@ApiOperation(value = "updateDocument", notes = "This will do a checkout and 
checkin services", response = Response.class, responseContainer = "application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public String updateDocument(String data) {
      return data;
}
```

Using this, Model Schema is displayed empty on Swagger UI for this operation. Unless I create Java model class, Model Schema is not displayed.
Can some one give some idea, How to get the Schema definition for JSON data types? My Restful Service accepts JSON and process JSON without using any Java Models.

Using Java Models, needs unnecessary conversions of the data.

Is there any flexibility for the JSON definition file can be created and linked instead of the Java Model?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per your method declaration, It takes a `String` as a argument.  This is all that swagger can read. How will it know that this String can be a json and it can be of xyz structure. So it cannot display you model schema, Unless you specify a Java Model

Comment: Hi @pvpkiran, thanks for the reply. Is it possible to link externally defined open API Schema definition in `swagger2 annotations`? If required, I can define the `JSON Schema definitions` with open API and maintain outside of the Java file. Can you let me know if there is any possibility?